# Looking for digital asset management tool where assets are tagged and added manually

Tags: digital-asset-management, asset-management

I have a wide variety of file types (software packages, video tutorials, books, etc...), and many of them, that are stored in an inconvenient manner, e.g.:

1. Many reside in `X:\deliverables` and cannot be moved from there
2. Many of them are zipped and divided to certain file size (e.g. `pack.a00`, `pack.a01`, ..., `pack.a72`)
3. Some have file names that cannot not be changed and do not make any sense (e.g. `protoRFC-830.docx`)
4. Some are offline in some external storage
5. Some are just web-links...

I want to create a catalog of all these files, so whenever I need to find certain package, I just search for that and find where it is located.

1. Adding files are carried out manually - no need for scanning
2. Tagging - very important! I need the ability to tag certain package, and be able to search by tags as well (e.g. `software`, `graphics`, `open-source`, `vector`, `media-conversion`, ...).
3. It would be great if this tagging system would be somewhat sophisticated, like tags can be related to others, or there is a tree-like tags structures (a `vector` is type of `graphics`)
4. Content indexing is almost of no use in this case - search for files is done by data inserted manually (description, notes, tags) ...
5. ... although files properties ***are*** important: the capability to search by size, extension, file-creation/alteration-time, and so on

The killer feature: Windows explorer integration (right-click -> set folder tags, description, etc...)